# How to print SSL packet details with tshark?

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, tshark

I collected a brief exchange between an SSL client and server (openssl's `s_client` and `s_server`, to be exact), and want to view the ssl portions of the pcap file with `tshark`. I don't need to decrypt the encrypted portions, but at least would like to know the values in the unencrypted fields.

When copying the file from the server to my desktop I can open the pcap file with Wireshark and see the fields by default:

[image: wireshark output]

On the other hand, `tshark -r tls_dump.pcap` only displays up to the TCP portion of the packets. For example, for the same packet:

```
4 0.000069237    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    TCP 373 54312 → 44330 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=43776 Len=307 ...
```

I tried collecting the packets both with `tcpdump -U -i lo 'port 44330' -w tls_dump.pcap` and with `tshark -nn -i lo -s 0 -w tls_dump.pcap port 44330` (as [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/413835/sniff-ssl-handshake-using-tshark)), but when trying to view the packets the results are the same.

`tshark` options I tried:

- `-2` has no effect
- `-2R "ssl"` shows nothing
- `-Y "ssl"` shows nothing
- `-o "ssl.desegment_ssl_records: TRUE" -o "ssl.desegment_ssl_application_data: TRUE"` has no effect
- `-T json` shows only raw uninterpreted TCP payload data
- `-V` shows only raw uninterpreted TCP payload data
- `--print` has no effect
- `--enable-protocol "ssl"` has no effect
- `--enable-heuristic "ssl"` gives me a `No such protocol ssl, can't enable` error

How does one output SSL packet details of an SSL packet with `tshark`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What worked in the end was specifying the port using `-d tcp.port==44330,ssl`, thus my full command was:

```
tshark -r tls_dump.pcap -d tcp.port==44330,ssl
```

The reason this was necessary was due to some version-specific differences in Wireshark. My desktop had version `2.6.0`, which was able to automatically detect the SSL protocol. The server had version `2.4.6`, which wasn't able to detect SSL and needed the port number to be specified.

Only SSL packets can be printed with:

```
tshark -r tls_dump.pcap -d tcp.port==44330,ssl -2R "ssl"
```

Only SSL packets in JSON format:

```
tshark -r tls_dump.pcap -d tcp.port==44330,ssl -2R "ssl" -T json
```